# Did the Romans eat breakfast?

Tags: ancient-rome, food

[This BBC article](http://www.bbc.com/news/magazine-20243692), citing the food historian Caroline Yeldham, says

> Breakfast as we know it didn't exist for large parts of history. **The
>   Romans didn't really eat it**, usually consuming only one meal a day
>   around noon, says food historian Caroline Yeldham. In fact, breakfast
>   was actively frowned upon.

Quoting her directly, the article continues,

> "They were obsessed with digestion and **eating more than one meal was
>   considered a form of gluttony**."

This [Smithsonian article](https://www.smithsonianmag.com/smart-news/mostly-old-and-ill-ate-breakfast-until-rise-working-man-180954041/) more or less says the same thing and cites Yeldham in the BBC article. It's heading is

> **Mostly the Old And Ill Ate Breakfast Until the Rise of the Working Man**

and the sub-heading is

> **Romans disdained the meal**, few ate it in the Middle Ages, but most eat
>   breakfast now

Caroline Yeldham has been described as "eminent" by [historynewsnetwork](https://historynewsnetwork.org/article/38012) and "well-known" by this [University of Leeds article](https://www.leeds.ac.uk/news/article/3551/medieval_dishes_on_the_menu), but several other sources seem to at least partially contradict her.

Wikipedia's article [Ancient Roman Cuisine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_Roman_cuisine) says

> Traditionally, **a breakfast called ientaculum[1](http://www.bbc.com/news/magazine-20243692) was served at dawn**.

and [this article](http://www.tribunesandtriumphs.org/roman-life/ancient-roman-meals.htm) seems to agree, even citing details of the meal:

> The usual time for their breakfast was early in the
>   morning. The ientaculum, or breakfast, consisted of a buffet of flat,
>   round loaves seasoned with salt were eaten. Rich ancient Romans, the
>   Patricians would also have eggs, cheese, honey, milk and fruit
>   included in these early meals

[This article](http://www.empirerome.com/wordpress/?page_id=599) seems to fall somewhere in-between, saying "Romans were not big on breakfast" and that it was not a major meal.

From the conflicting information above, it seems that some Romans ate at least a 'smallish' breakfast. I would also surmise that farmers and soldiers probably ate some kind of breakfast, though there is also a reference to patricians.

**Was there any particular class of Romans which didn't eat breakfast and considered it 'gluttony'?**

**Or are the somewhat conflicting accounts due to differences over time?** (none of the sources are time-specific and [Ancient Rome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_Rome) covers a period of over 1,000 years)

**Did the later Romans, under the influence of Christianity, drop breakfast?** I mention this because, due to the influence of Christianity, breakfast was not common in early medieval Europe.

Comment: The whole premise seems to rely on the british/american view of a breakfast as a gargantuan meal. No, Romans didn't have those, but as justCal answers points to, they probably had the same kind of light breakfast all the mediterranean cultures still have today.

Comment: @Rekesoft I see your point, and I can't speak for Americans as I haven't lived there. In the UK, though, the big breakfast has gone 'out of fashion' https://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/uknews/7593760/Two-thirds-of-Britons-do-not-eat-breakfast.html It's possible, though, that Caroline Yeldham was thinking about traditional breakfasts but, being a food expert, that would be a little surprising I think.

Comment: I agree with Lars; while traditions of course vary across the nation (and indeed within regions), speaking very generally a British breakfast in 2018 is, like, a slice of toast and a glass of orange juice. Maybe with some crushed avocado on it if you're one of _those_ people... ;) (on the toast, not on the orange juice)

Comment: @Rekesoft: Breakfast in America is not usually a gargantuan meal for most people.  It's often a bowl of cereal with milk & fruit, or perhaps toast or a bagel, and a cup or two of coffee.  The sort of cooked breakfast you're probably thinking of - bacon or sausage, eggs, toast &c is more of a holiday or special occasion thing, often eaten later in the morning and combined with the midday meal as "brunch".

Comment: its worth remembering that the time available and money available to the average Roman varied hugely over the long lifetime of the Roman empire; "typical" can only really be gathered with a fix on a particular time-frame.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

It seems the issue may be with generalizing 'Romans' as single entity and not as a group which changed through time. Johnston in [The Private Life of the Romans](http://www.forumromanum.org/life/johnston_8.html) goes into the changes seen in the Roman diet over time:

> The table supplies of a given people vary from age to age with the
> development of civilization and refinement, and in the same age with
> the means and tastes of classes and individuals. Of the Romans it may
> be said that **during the early Republic, perhaps almost through the
> second century B.C**., they cared little for the pleasures of the
> table. They lived frugally and ate sparingly. They were almost
> strictly vegetarians (§ 273), much of their food was eaten cold, and
> the utmost simplicity characterized the cooking and the service of
> their meals.

But later:

> The last two centuries of the Republic saw all this changed. The
> conquest of Greece and the wars in Asia Minor gave the Romans a taste
> of Eastern luxury and altered their simple table customs, as other
> customs had been altered by like contact with the outside world.

This led to some new behaviors:

> Some of the very rich, on the other hand, aping the luxury of the
> Greeks but lacking their refinement, became gluttons instead of
> gourmets. They ransacked the world for articles of food,4 preferring
> the rare and the costly to what was really palatable and delicate. The
> separate dining room (*trīclīnium*) was introduced, the great houses
> having two or more (§ 204), and the oecī (§ 207) were, perhaps,
> pressed into service for banquet halls. The dining couch (§§ 224, 304)
> took the place of the bench or stool, slaves served the food to the
> reclining guests, a dinner dress (§ 249) was devised, and every
> familia urbāna (§ 149) included a high-priced chef with a staff of
> trained assistants.

Johnson is of the opinion that breakfast was eaten, but it was definitely not 'the most important meal of the day' for the later Romans:

> In early times in the city and in all periods in the country the chief
> meal (*cēna*) was eaten in the middle of the day, preceded by a
> breakfast (*ientāculum*) in the early morning and followed in the
> evening by a supper (*vesperna*).

Concerning the *ientāculum* itself:

> 302. Breakfast and Luncheon. The breakfast (*ientāculum* or *iantāculum*) was eaten immediately after rising, the hour varying, of course, with
>      the occupation and social position of the individual. Usually it
>      consisted merely of bread, eaten dry or dipped in wine or sprinkled
>      over with salt, though raisins, olives, and cheese were sometimes
>      added. Workmen pressed for time seem to have taken their breakfast in
>      their hands to eat as they went to the place of their labor, and
>      schoolboys often stopped on their way to school (§ 122) at a public
>      bakery (§ 286) to buy a sort of shortcake or pancake on which they
>      made a hurried breakfast. More rarely the breakfast became a regular
>      meal: eggs were served in addition to the things just mentioned, and
>      mulsum (§ 298) and milk were drunk with them.

So it seems references to Romans not eating three meals a day may be referring to the earlier Republic times, but later the breakfast was definitely part of the schedule.

Comment: Keep in mind this varied by wealth and other factors. We know soldiers ate breakfasts -- because the failure to give them time to prepare and eat breakfast was so notable at the Battle of Trebia.

Comment: Yes, the quotes from Johnston mention that diet varied by social class, '.Some of the very rich'...'varying, of course, with the occupation and social position of the individual.'

Comment: @justCal -- sorry, I didn't see any specific reference to breakfast in that quote.